# UserInactivity component calls function in succession, not at timed interval

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-user-inactivity](https://github.com/jkomyno/react-native-user-inactivity) to fire `silentRenew` and renew the access token for my app, if my current token expires while the user is still using it to save them getting kicked out. This is the only place in my app where the function gets called but is getting called alot more frequent than the 30 second interval `timeForInactivity={30000}`

`silentRenew` seems to fire in succession. How can I get silentRenew to fire every 30 seconds, and not spam the login service?

```
import UserInactivity from 'react-native-user-inactivity';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-user-inactivity/lib/BackgroundTimer';
    const UserActivityMonitor = (props) => {
        const { children } = props;
        ...
        const handleIsActive = async (isActive) => {
            ...
                
                    try {
                        const success = await silentRenew();
                        console.log(success)
                        if (success === true) {
                            setValidToken(success);
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        logger.error(
                            'Error occured while monitoring user activity',
                            e,
                        );
                    }
              
        };
    
        return (
            <>
                <UserInactivity
                    timeoutHandler={BackgroundTimer}
                    timeForInactivity={30000}
                    onAction={handleIsActive}
                >
                    {children}
                </UserInactivity>
            </>
        );
    };
    export { UserActivityMonitor };
```

silentRenew:

```
const silentRenew = async () => {
    try {
        const authdata = await getItem(AUTH_DATA);
        if (authdata) {
            const {
                refreshToken,
            } = JSON.parse(authdata);
            if (refreshToken) {
                await refreshAuthToken(refreshToken);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('Error occurred while slient renew', e);
        return false;
    }
};
```

App.js:

```
 <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <AppContextProvider>
        <NetworkProvider
          pingInterval={toNumber(networkCheckConfig.pingInterval)}
          pingServerUrl={networkCheckConfig.pingServerUrl}
        >

          <NavigationContainer
            initialState={initialState}
            ref={navigationRef}
            onReady={() => {
              isReadyRef.current = true;
            }}
            onStateChange={(state) => {
              setItem(NAVIGATION_STATE, JSON.stringify(state));
            }}
          >
            <UserActivityMonitor>
              <AppRootStack />
            </UserActivityMonitor>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </NetworkProvider>
      </AppContextProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: Could it be that your component containing `<UserInactivity>` is mounting/un-mounting multiple times? Or that it is being instantiated more than once?

Comment: Thanks, how can I check for that?

Comment: Where are you importing your `UserActivityMonitor` component?

Comment: Thanks, in app.js

Comment: Edited answer...

Comment: Do you want to call `silentRenew` every 30 seconds only if the user is still active?

Comment: Yes that would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did some tests after reading the library's [documentation](https://github.com/jkomyno/react-native-user-inactivity) and it seems that `onAction` is intended to be fired each time user is "inactive" (when there is no interaction for a time longer than `timeForInactivity`), but also for each time there actually is an interaction. The real indicator of user activity then is the value of the passed `isActive` argument.

Knowing this and assuming that you want to run `silentRenew` every 30 seconds only if the user is active, you'll have to make some changes:

```js
import React, {useCallback, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import UserInactivity from 'react-native-user-inactivity';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-user-inactivity/lib/BackgroundTimer';

const timeForInactivity = 30000;
const refreshInterval = 30000;

const UserActivityMonitor = (props) => {
    const {children} = props;

    const isActiveRef = useRef(true);

    const handler = useCallback((isActive) => {
        isActiveRef.current = isActive;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (isActiveRef.current) {
                // REFRESH TOKEN HERE.
            }
        }, refreshInterval);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <UserInactivity
                timeoutHandler={BackgroundTimer}
                timeForInactivity={timeForInactivity}
                onAction={handler}>
                {children}
            </UserInactivity>
        </>
    );
};

export {UserActivityMonitor};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: For my learning could you explain why useRef is required?

Comment: @Bomber `useRef` is used to store "instance values" that will not trigger a re-render when changed. I don't know if you ever used React class components, but it would be the same as doing `this.isActive = true;`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). Please let me know if it is still not clear.